# How can I access the element of my own array class by the square brackets overload?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Take a look at this simplified version of what I'm coding and you'll understand the problem...

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int N = 2>
class Array
{
    T m_arr[N]{ 0 };
    int m_size = N;
public:
    T& operator[](const int& index) { return m_arr[index]; }
};

int main()
{
    Array<int, 10>* thing = new Array<int, 10>();
    thing[2] = 5;
    std::cout << thing[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Now, obviously the first thing that comes to mind is, hey, just like I overloaded the [] operator, lets overload the = and the << operators, but that wouldn't work, since that is only valid for doing something like this...

```
thing = whatever;
std::cout << thing << std::endl;
```

But how could I do it for...

```
thing[num] = whatever;
std::cout << thing[num] << std::endl;
```

Comment: For your code as written,  `thing` is a pointer to an `Array`, so use `(*thing)[2]` to access an element of the `Array` itself.     More generally, don't use pointers in `main()`.   Do `Array<int, 10> thing;  thing[2] = 5; std::cout << thing[2]`.     (C++ is not Java or whatever other language you're used to, so use it differently).

Comment: @Peter I've never programmed in Java, but anyway, what if I need to create that array on the heap? Wouldn't I need to use a pointer?

Comment: @Peter Cause I'm trying to do my own array and vector classes (even thought they might be inefficient but It's just for fun), and you don't write `(*thing)[2]` when your trying to access an element in the standard vector class, so how did they do it?

Comment: @Karlos It's because you hold a vector and not a pointer to a vector, otherwise you'd need the *

Comment: @Karlos - You either create a pointer to the array named `thing`, which means the object can be dynamically allocated, is named `(*thing)`, and its third element is accessed using `(*thing)[2]`  OR you create an object named `thing` and access its third element as `thing[2]`.    You are trying to use a pointer to a dynamically allocated object, but to use it as if it is an actual object - you can't mix things that way.   And the reason for my comment on another language is that your code uses a technique commonly used in other languages, but not in C++.

Comment: If you want the array to be on the heap, then just do that internally in the class.

Comment: In *modern* C++, the general guidance is to AVOID using raw pointers wherever possible entirely   (there are exceptions to that statement, but it is true more often than not).   Use standard containers or smart pointer types (both object types that manage a pointer or something that behaves like a pointer internally) if you want pointer semantics in a safer way.   If you want to program in C++ like people did 30 years ago, then worry about using pointers and "creating objects of the heap".

Comment: @Peter But then, if you create a `std::vector<type>*` that means, on the heap, you don't access it with `*(vecname)[2]`, you just write `vecname[2]` so how did they implement that in the `std::vector` class?

Comment: @Karlos - They didn't.  You're misunderstanding how the vector class is used and misunderstanding the relationship between pointers and arrays or objects.   If you create a `std::vector<int> *vecname= new std::vector<int>(3)` then you access its elements as `(*vecname)[2]`.   `vecname[2]` is something else entirely (and, in this case, gives undefined behaviour).

Comment: @Peter I'm not trying to program like a 30 y.o. I'm just trying to understand how the stl classes work by creating them myself, how am I gonna work with smart pointers and not understanding how they work, or even the raw pointers..

Comment: @Peter doesn't mean cause something is new you gotta use it, I rather use raw pointers and knowing exactly what's going on with em, but anyway, I've been coding for a year so I ain't no expert but I really wanna know how things work and not just using em cos they do work..

Comment: @Karlos - Doing that sort of thing for learning is fine. Problem is, you're not understanding the relationship between pointers, arrays, and objects. Your assumption in your code that `thing[2]` should call `Array::operator[]()` is flat out wrong.  With `Array<int, 10>* thing = new Array<int, 10>()`,  `thing[0]` (equivalently `*thing`) accesses the object created with operator `new`.  `thing[2]` does not exist so even accessing it gives undefined behaviour.   `*thing` is the `Array` object created with operator `new`.   So `(*thing)[2]` calls your `operator[]()` function.

Comment: @Karlos simply replace your `Array` class (which is coded fine) with [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), and you will see the `main()` code you have shown still fails, until you replace `thing[2]` with `(*thing)[2]`, or replace `array<int, 10>* thing = new array<int, 10>();` with `array<int, 10> thing;`.